# Let the font stretch to fill the cell

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik

In the cells of the telerik gridview. `<telerik:GridViewDataColumn`

I have the following example.
[image]

You see the first cell is regular font. The second one is bold. It is ugly. I want them having the same width, which means I have to stretch them to 100% width of the cell.

How to do it?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming it's a `TextBlock`, use a justified alignment:

```
<TextBlock TextAlignment="Justify" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I updated the question.  It is telerik  thing.